# iOS developer certificate expired

Tags: objective-c, ios

I recently have renewed my iOS membership by paying the $99 fee. However, it seems that all my certificates have expired so I am trying to renew them manually. So I went into the provisioning portal--> Certificates --> Development and issued a new certificate which I downloaded. So now I have .cer file downloaded from Apple. I believe last time around all I had to do was double click this file and it would ask if I wanted to add it to the keychain.

This time, nothing happens other than the fact keychain access is launched but it does not ask me anything and I do not see the certificate in the certificate section or key section.

What do I need to do to get this file into Xcode to continue development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into XCode Option Devices, select Provisioning Profiles and then click on Refresh in the corner on the right bottom.

Comment: Did the trick... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Here:](http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/buildingiphoneapps/2010/4/8/how-to-renew-iphone-development-certificate.html)

> Once you get the new profiles, download them and import them in Xcode Organizer then sync with the development devices. You are done.